# где найти заземление

Tags: микроконтроллеры, arduino, avr

есть AVR - ATmega32, и есть плата, в которой она уютно сидит. плата наподобие Arduino.

на плате есть удобные выводы по бокам для всех портов (A, B, C, D), и даже Vcc, а вот GND вытащить забыли. и сейчас, чтобы просто замерить напряжение, мне нужно вставать на ногу самого контроллера, а ещё и держать там щуп, что совсем неудобно. а недавно появилась необходимость подключить диоды на беспаечную плату, а замли то нет.

предположим, что я вообще не знаю электроники.

как мне провести землю/ноль/-/GND на беспаечную/монтажную плату?

нужно для светодиодов и датчика температуры.
не припаиваться же к ноге контроллера.

[image: плата]

Comment: Схему и фото платы приложите.

Comment: Касательно оффтопика: по-моему, принадлежность этому сайту подобных вопросов просто не обсуждалась. Обсудим на Мете?

Comment: @D-side: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2425

Comment: Решили, что вопрос по теме, так что обнулил голоса на закрытие.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Там есть разъем ISP. У него 4 пина - это GND.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сработало! только ISP у меня постоянно занят программатором, но рядом есть JTAG. нашёл распиновку обоих итерфейсов, картинку прилагаю. спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

распиновка интерфейсов ISP и JTAG. 
вывел землю из десятого пина, хотя второй тоже работает как ноль.

[image: isp-and-jtag-pinout]

*оффтоп: спасибо всем участникам обсуждения.*